# android apk update: what do I know of last version?

Tags: android, version, apk, upgrade

I have 2 versions of my app, both have android:versionCode="1" in the manifest.

1. One version (versionCode=1) was distributed by email.
2. Other version (also versionCode=1) was published on google play.

The versionCode is the same, but the apk is not. One value in their properties file (raw resource release.properties) differs. This property makes their behaviour a bit different.

If I publish a new version (versionCode=2), both will be updated. That is okay, but I would like this different behaviour to persist. But can I? I did not write the properties file to disk, it is inside the old apk and will be overwritten.

I thought of lots of things, but cannot seem to think of a way in which I can keep the two version behaving differently, because I only know the last versionCode on an update, and I know nothing else of this last version, or do I?

Is there a solution to this problem? Any ideas about what I can try?

Comment: are both apks signed with the same keystore file? If not, the one distributed via email will not get updated  - google play will detect that it is installed from different source.

Comment: sadly, both use the same keystore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the correct answer is that there is no solution....

Answer (score 0):

You should have given the version you distributed by email a different package-name.

If your e-mail distribution is still small, I would change the package-name and redistribute it with this changed package-name. Users on the e-mail distribution won't be able to 'update', though and this may be a big problem. But if your e-mail distribution is small, this problem may be not so big.

Comment: the e-mail distribution is large already, and redistributing it is almost impossible.

Comment: Ay... The best you can do have different version schemes: E.g. New Google Play versions start with 2 and end with 1000000. Email versions start with 1000002 and end with 2000000. This means, though, that Google Play users can update from email, but not vice versa.

Comment: Ay for sure :) I will surely look into that next time, but for me right now both have versionCode 1, so this is not really an option anymore. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: You can increase the version code from 1 to 1000002 with no problem. Update from 1 to 1000002 would work fine. As long as future updates have version code 1000003 or higher, you should be fine.

Comment: but that would upgrade both versions to 1000002, won't it?

Comment: If a user has your app installed from Google Play and then decides to install it from the e-mail distribution, yes, their version will be upgraded to the e-mail version and reverting back to the Google Play version will not be possible unless they uninstall. There is no way around that. And you need to run two separate builds, one for Google Play with version-code < 1000000, the other for email with version-code >= 1000000

Comment: yes, well, too late for that now. they're already out there and installed.